# Google Compute Engine: boot disk smaller than 10GB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In Google Compute Engine, is it possible to create an instance with a boot disk that is smaller than 10GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to do so? If you did, in the console the error is worded like so:

> Disk size cannot be smaller than the size of chosen disk image (10 GB)

As of May 2019, most [public images](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/images) are 10 GB or larger. CoreOS gets by with a 9 GB image, and 9 GB is the default disk size when creating an instance from it in the console.

---

Note that the [performance quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) at the minimum size is rubbish. Seperate data disks or SSD type is required for anything but idle workloads.

> Use [the 10 GB] volume size only for boot volumes. I/O bursting will be
>   relied upon for any meaningful tasks.

Comment: Agreed. I also tried through the web interface and could not create a disk smaller than that, whether boot or not.